# Pandas un-exponde Series based off of Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, series

I have a pd.dataframe of sentences such as:

```
    text
0   kusebenta ngendlela lefanele kwemabhizinisi em...
1   bumetima ekuvisiseni umnotfo wemhlaba nekuntji...
2   ngaleyo ndlelake sesincume kusebentisa emandla...
3   emabhisizinisi embuso kufanele angenise imali ...
4   nanoma kulungile kutsi umbuso uwasite ngetimal...
... ...
63121   alimata nobe enta kutsi kulahleke imphahla yem...
63122   afaka engotini imphilo yakhe nobe yalabanye ng...
63123   akhinyabeta kuphatfwa kucondziswa kwetigwegwe ...
63124   asebentisa kabi sikhundla sakhe emisebentini y...
63125   antjontja afumbatsisa nobe enta inkohliso
```

I have a pd.series of sentences I got after exploding the pd.dataframe containing sentences like so:

```py
series1 = df1['field_name'].str.split().explode()
```

This gives the pd.series:

```
0               kusebenta
0               ngendlela
0                lefanele
0          kwemabhizinisi
0                  embuso
0                    tate
0                   owned
0             enterprises
0           kungumgogodla
0             wentfutfuko
0                  yelive
1                bumetima
1             ekuvisiseni
1                 umnotfo
1                wemhlaba
1    nekuntjintjantjintja
1                   kwawo
1                 emandla
1              etimakethe
1                   kanye
Name: text, dtype: object
```

I want to now un-explode and recombine the words from the pd.series to make the full sentence again after I do some processing on the series.

I have been looking at using 'groupby' but have not had much success when trying to groupby the index.

I have also tried to convert it into a pd.dataframe, but got errors about having the same index.

P.S. would it be possible to create a new DF with indexes up to the length of the pd.series and then concat the pd.series data somehow as full sentences or use groupby that way?

EDIT 1:
Running `vocab.head().to_dict()` as suggested in comment produces the following output:
`{0: 'embuso'}`
Which is the 5th element as head gives 5 results by default.

Running `vocab.head(20).to_dict()` produces:
`{0: 'yelive', 1: 'kanye'}`
The last element with index 0 being 'yelive', and 'kanye' being an element from the 'index 1'

Comment: Do `df.head().to_dict()` and add the output data to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `str.join` on index generated by `explode()`:

```
>>>  series1.groupby(level=0).apply(' '.join)
0    kusebenta ngendlela lefanele kwemabhizinisi em...
1    bumetima ekuvisiseni umnotfo wemhlaba nekuntji...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you, I used `groupby(level=0)` before, but `apply(...)` was the magic answer!